# Grails/Groovy RegEx ReplaceAll

Tags: regex, groovy

I'm trying to insert /01/ into date. Here is the list of sample dates.

```
Example:
Blah blah 08/2000 blah blah.
Blah 10/2001 blah blah blah.
01/2003 blah blah.

Desired Result:
Blah blah 08/01/2000 blah blah.
Blah 10/01/2001 blah blah blah.
01/01/2003 blah blah.

Actual Result: ( it takes the last match found and replace everything)
Blah blah 01/01/2003 blah blah.
Blah 01/01/2003 blah blah blah.
01/01/2003 blah blah.
```

This is what I have.

```
def MONTH = /\d{1,2}/
def YEAR = /\d{2,4}/
def date = /($MONTH)\W($YEAR)/

(example =~ date).each {match, month, year ->
    def dayDate = month + "/01/" + year
    result = example.replaceAll(~date, dayDate)
}
```

Since it is using `each` method, I thought it would insert `/01/` as it goes but I didn't expect it to replace all matches to the last found match. 
What can I do to just insert?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
def MONTH = /\d{1,2}/
def YEAR = /\d{2,4}/ 
def date = /($MONTH)\W($YEAR)/  

def example = '''
Blah blah 08/2000 blah blah. 
Blah 10/2001 blah blah blah. 
01/2003 blah blah.
'''

example.replaceAll(~date, { _, month, year -> "${month}/01/${year}" } )
```

In your code, `result` is setted for each match : so only the last value of "result" is the value of the last match. In this last match, you are replacing all match of a date pattern to the value of the last match.

In groovy, replaceAll can take a closure, and in this case, for each match of the regex, the match is replaced by the return value of the closure.

Comment: Thank you, it worked with some syntax changes. I used `example.replaceAll(date) { match, month, year -> "${month}/01/${year}" }`

Answer (score 1):

With capturing groups you can capture the `months` and `year` and replace `date` between it.

**Regex:** `/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/`

**Flags to use:**

- `g` for global search.

**Replacement to do:** Replace with `\1/01/\2`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aV3lU4/5)**

---

An alternate solution would be to use `lookaround` assertions like this.

**Regex:** `(?<=\d{2}\/)(?=\d{4})`

**Explanation:**

- This regex finds the **spot** between `10/` and `2000` where you want to place date `01/`. Hence after replacing it becomes `10/01/2000`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aV3lU4/3)**

Comment: Thank you. This is great to know. I checked out Regex101.com. It's awesome. I wish they had Groovy or Java code generator though.

Comment: @monty_bean: There must be one out there.

Comment: Java online testers: [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html), [OCPSoft](http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/).

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew